# I am having problems running Facebook FQL queries that include long user ids

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, userid

I am having problems running queries with FQL that include a supplied "Large"(beginning with 10000..) User ID

here is an example of one that is not working:

```
fql?q=SELECT uid, first_name,last_name,pic,pic_square,name 
        FROM user 
        WHERE uid=100002445083370
```

Is there a way to encapsulate the long number so it's passed as a string?

here is another example:

```
/fql?q=SELECT src_big 
    FROM photo 
    WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid 
                    FROM album 
                    WHERE  owner=100002445083370 AND type="profile") 
    ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1
```

Has anyone been able to solve this issue?  I am testing the queries in the graph explorer with no luck as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what the problem is,

The User id I am trying to pass is supposed to be: "100002445083367",  but from querying the list of friends and grabbing their User Id, I am getting back "uid":1.0000244508337e+14 which is being shortened to: 100002445083370 (php removing the e+14) throwing off the second query.  I need to make sure the id I am grabbing is staying as a string value not a number while I pass it back and forth from PHP and Javascript.

The problem is because of the way PHP handles JSON_DECODE.  I had to modify Facebook PHP SDK and add a preg_replace previous to the json_decode.  It will make sure json_decode doesn't convert large integers to floats by first converting them to strings.

here is the code:
line 803 from base_facebook.php:

```
$result = json_decode(preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $this->_oauthRequest($this->getUrl($domainKey, $path),$params)), true);
```

here is more information on the subject: 
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=20846

Comment: Wow!  Excellent description of what's going on.  I'd file a bug against the PHP SDK so they can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "not working"?
That query works for me in Graph API explorer but the response is

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

I think that user-id isn't valid;  https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100002445083370 gives a "Page not found" error for me.